# inherit product_id_change and add new argument odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8

i'm working on sale.order.line ,adding new field lot
[image: wizard orderline]

```
lot = fields.Many2one('stock.production.lot','lot')
```

and i want pass this field as argument into an inherited method (onchange on quantity )

```
def product_id_change(self, cr, uid, ids, pricelist, product, qty=0,                                                                
                      uom=False, qty_uos=0, uos=False, name='', partner_id=False,                                                   
                      lang=False, update_tax=True, date_order=False, packaging=False,                                               
                      fiscal_position=False, flag=False, lot=False,context=None):                                                   

    res = super(order_line, self).product_id_change(cr, uid, ids,                                                                   
                                                    pricelist, product,                                                             
                                                    qty,uom, qty_uos,                                                               
                                                    uos, name, partner_id,                                                          
                                                    lang, update_tax,                                                               
                                                    date_order, packaging,                                                          
                                                    fiscal_position,                                                                
                                                    flag, context=context)                                                          


    if product:                                                                                                                     
        print "----------------------------------------------"                                                                      
        print lot                                                                                                                   
        print "----------------------------------------------"                                                                  
        # res['value']['changement_prix'] = lot.change_prix                                                                         
        # res['value']['old_price'] = res['value']['price_unit']                                                                    
        # res['value']['price_unit'] = res['value']['old_price'] + lot.change_prix                                                  
    return res
```

but all i got in my print is False for lot
so im wondering how to pass lot as argument on this function 
thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass new argument this way in function.

Its call super method of object, it will create problem in the super method also. So either you can pass lot in context for xml side,

like

```
    <field name="product_id"
 context="{'partner_id':parent.partner_id, 
 'quantity':product_uom_qty,
 'pricelist':parent.pricelist_id, 
 'uom':product_uom, 'company_id': parent.company_id, 
 'lot': lot}" <======
groups="base.group_user"
 on_change="product_id_change(parent.pricelist_id, product_id, product_uom_qty, False, product_uos_qty, False, name, parent.partner_id, False, True, parent.date_order, False, parent.fiscal_position, False, context)"/>
```

So in context you get you passed the lot.

```
lot = context.get('lot')
```

in python side you get from context and done your code.

Otherwise you have to overwrite whole function of onchange in your new modules
change in xml side for arguements of onchange

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thnx for the answer ,, im not getting errors but 
my print show lot = None 
is it because i'm using orderline in wizard forme ?may be ?

Answer (score 0):

well i couldnt get lot by context 
so i made an invisible field many2one in product.product
and save it there .
than get it back later by browsing my product
thnx